# Animate being triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so I am trying to make a simple slider but what's happening is that my variable current image is being increased 3 times (ie: animations callback being triggered multiple times for some reason)

```
var currentImage = 0;

$("#1").show();

setInterval(slider,5000);

function slider()
{
    $(".slider img").animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function() {
        $("#"+currentImage).hide();
        if(currentImage <= 3)
        {
            currentImage++;
        }
        else
        {
            currentImage = 1;
        }
        $("#"+currentImage).show();
        console.log(currentImage); //print 1, 2, 3 each time it gets called
        showSlider();
    });
}
function showSlider()
{
    $(".slider img").animate({"opacity":1}, 500);
}
```

Callback itself behaves like it's inside a loop

I've attached a screenshot of the console log that gets printed everytime[image]

Comment: Don't just post a screen shot and code fragment, provide a [mcve].

Comment: After looking at your last 2 questions and answers, it appears you misunderstood what SO is for. It is a QA site where both questions and answers are suppose to help future users as well, and for that to be possible, an issue needs to be reproduced within the question, and you fail to do so repeatedly. Please reread [ask].

Answer (score -1):

Alright so the problem was that I had 3 image tags that I was swapping. The animate itself was being triggered 3 times as it gets called for every element.

How I fixed it was simply switching to promise

```
$(".slider img").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 500).promise().then(function() {
            $("#"+currentImage).hide();
            if(currentImage < 3)
            {
                currentImage++;
            }
            else
            {
                currentImage = 1;
            }
            $("#"+currentImage).show();
            console.log(currentImage);
            showSlider();
        });
```